# With a UK visa from Ghana, do I need another visa to leave the Netherlands to the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, ghanaian-citizens

I am a Ghanaian going to the Netherlands and onwards to the UK. Do Ineed a visa to enable me to continue my journey?

Answer (score 2):

No you don’t. If you have a visa for U.K. you can go there from anywhere as long as you have all the applicable transit visas.

Answer (score 1):

You should have no problem leaving the Netherlands going to the UK if you already hold a UK visa.

There is no separate document needed to exit the Netherlands.

You could still be refused entry to the UK if there was a problem with the visa such as a significant change in your circumstances after the visa was issued. This is uncommon though